# Select Text in vertical in Spyder text Editor (multiline editing editor)

Tags: spyder, text-editor

Is there a way for selecting text in vertical in Spyder3 Text Editor? What I mean is something equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Atom text editor for example:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, there's no way to do that in Spyder, sorry. Unfortunately it's not so easy to implement it with our current editor code.

Comment: Thank you @Carlos. One question more: is it possible the integration of an existing open source editor in the Spyder-IDE?

Comment: No, that's not possible either. There are many improvements to our Editor that will come in Spyder 4 (folding, indentation guidelines, autosaving) and I think what you mention is perhaps the last thing we need to address to make people happy. We'll try to add it for Spyder 4 too.

Comment: the problem I have it is exactly the indentation: sometimes it is 4 space, sometimes is a tab and the purpose is to modify all the line at the same time

Comment: This should be implemented in Spyder 5, which will be awesome. Discussion here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2112

Answer (score 0):

You can write text code in 'sublime' editor and perform all sorts of shortcuts there. to select matching text in the sublime editor, first select/highlight that text using the cursor and then press Ctrl+D as many times you want, sublime will keep highlighting matching text in the whole text file. To select all matching entries simply press Alt+F3 (in windows).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).